# How to calculate annual and last 3 months sales

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have Order, OrderDetail, and Vendor entities. How can I obtain **annual**, **last 3 months' total sales data**, and **a total number of orders data** on a vendor basis from the entities consisting of these sample data? I tried but I'm not very familiar with Linq. By the way, I am using EF Core 6.

I got an invalid anonymous type member when I try to implement linq on the dotnetfiddle.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
        // Order collection
        IList<Order> orderList = new List<Order>() { 
                new Order() { Id = 1, OrderDateTime = new DateTime(2019, 11, 12, 22, 45, 12, 004), CustomerName = "ABC", Status = "Completed",DoneBy="Cenk"} ,
                new Order() { Id = 2, OrderDateTime = new DateTime(2019, 11, 12, 22, 45, 12, 004),  CustomerName = "A", Status = "Ccancelled",DoneBy="Cenk" } ,
                new Order() { Id = 3, OrderDateTime = new DateTime(2022, 07, 12, 22, 45, 12, 004),  CustomerName = "dsds", Status = "Contiues",DoneBy="Cenk" } ,
                new Order() { Id = 4, OrderDateTime = new DateTime(2022, 08, 12, 22, 45, 12, 004) , CustomerName = "dsds", Status = "Completed",DoneBy="Cenk"} ,
                new Order() { Id = 5, OrderDateTime = new DateTime(2022, 09, 12, 22, 45, 12, 004) , CustomerName = "jdsj",Status = "Completed",DoneBy="Cenk" } 
            };
        
        // OrderDetail collection
        IList<OrderDetail> orderDetailList = new List<OrderDetail>() { 
                new OrderDetail() { Id = 1, ProductCode = "12345", ProductName = "modem1",BuyQuantity=1,SellQuantity=10,CostRatio=2 , UnitCost=5,TotalBuyPrice=10,TotalSellPrice=15,Status = "Completed",ShippingNumber="Cenk", TrackingNumber="72827", Description="Test", OrderId=1, VendorId=1} ,
                new OrderDetail() { Id = 2, ProductCode = "Erf7899", ProductName = "modem2",BuyQuantity=2,SellQuantity=10,CostRatio=2 , UnitCost=5,TotalBuyPrice=10,TotalSellPrice=15,Status = "Contiunes",ShippingNumber="Cenk", TrackingNumber="72827", Description="Test", OrderId=1, VendorId=1 } ,
                new OrderDetail() { Id = 3, ProductCode = "0090owd", ProductName = "modem3",BuyQuantity=10,SellQuantity=15,CostRatio=2 , UnitCost=1,TotalBuyPrice=10,TotalSellPrice=15,Status = "Completed",ShippingNumber="Cenk", TrackingNumber="72827", Description="Test", OrderId=1, VendorId=1 } ,
                new OrderDetail() { Id = 4, ProductCode = "fse929", ProductName = "modem4",BuyQuantity=11,SellQuantity=15,CostRatio=2 , UnitCost=5,TotalBuyPrice=10,TotalSellPrice=15,Status = "Cancelled",ShippingNumber="Cenk", TrackingNumber="72827", Description="Test", OrderId=1, VendorId=2} ,
                new OrderDetail() { Id = 5, ProductCode = "1009ksks", ProductName = "modem5",BuyQuantity=19,SellQuantity=1,CostRatio=2 , UnitCost=1,TotalBuyPrice=10,TotalSellPrice=15,Status = "Completed",ShippingNumber="Cenk", TrackingNumber="72827", Description="Test", OrderId=1, VendorId=1 },
                new OrderDetail() { Id = 6, ProductCode = "556dhdk", ProductName = "modem6",BuyQuantity=9,SellQuantity=13,CostRatio=2 , UnitCost=5,TotalBuyPrice=10,TotalSellPrice=15,Status = "Completed",ShippingNumber="Cenk", TrackingNumber="72827", Description="Test", OrderId=1, VendorId=2 } ,
                new OrderDetail() { Id = 7, ProductCode = "99999", ProductName = "modem7",BuyQuantity=10,SellQuantity=14,CostRatio=2 , UnitCost=15,TotalBuyPrice=10,TotalSellPrice=15,Status = "Completed",ShippingNumber="Cenk", TrackingNumber="72827", Description="Test", OrderId=1, VendorId=2 }, 
                new OrderDetail() { Id = 8, ProductCode = "00000", ProductName = "modem8",BuyQuantity=1,SellQuantity=15,CostRatio=2 , UnitCost=1,TotalBuyPrice=10,TotalSellPrice=15,Status = "Completed",ShippingNumber="Cenk", TrackingNumber="72827", Description="Test", OrderId=1, VendorId=1 } 
            };
        
        // vendor collection
        IList<Vendor> vendorList = new List<Vendor>() { 
                new Vendor() { Id = 1, Name = "Vendor1", Address = "ABC Address", Email = "Email", PhoneNumber="1234353", MainResponsibleName="test", AssistantResponsibleName="test1"} ,
                new Vendor() { Id = 2, Name = "Vendor1", Address = "ABC Address", Email = "Email", PhoneNumber="1234353", MainResponsibleName="test", AssistantResponsibleName="test1" } 
                
            };
        
                 
         var data = orderList
            .Select(o => new { o.OrderDateTime.Year, o.OrderDateTime.Month, o.OrderDetails.Sum(d => d.TotalSellPrice)})
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.Year, x.Month }, (key, group) => new
            {
                yr = key.Year,
                mnth = key.Month,
                Price = group.Sum(k => k.TotalSellprice)
            }).ToList();
                          
        
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public DateTime OrderDateTime { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string DoneBy { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int BuyQuantity { get; set; }
    public int SellQuantity { get; set; }
    public double CostRatio { get; set; }
    public double UnitCost { get; set; }
    public double TotalBuyPrice { get; set; }
    public double TotalSellPrice { get; set; }
    public string ShippingNumber { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string TrackingNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int VendorId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
}

public class Vendor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string MainResponsibleName { get; set; }
    public string AssistantResponsibleName { get; set; }
    public List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

}
```

## Edit 1

I ran the query without any errors on LinqPad, but I couldn't fetch the data as requested.

```
OrdersDetails.GroupBy(x => new { Year = x.Order.OrderDateTime.Year, Month = x.Order.OrderDateTime.Month })
.Select(u => new 
        {
            Year = u.Key.Year,
            Month = u.Key.Month,
            TotalPrice = u.Sum(x => x.TotalSellPrice)
            
        })
```

[image]

Sample data

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ON
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders] ([Id], [OrderDateTime], [CustomerName], [Status], [DoneBy]) VALUES (1, N'2022-06-07 16:46:21', N'customer1', N'Completed', N'test1111')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders] ([Id], [OrderDateTime], [CustomerName], [Status], [DoneBy]) VALUES (2, N'2022-06-08 00:00:00', N'Vestel', N'Continues', N'Cenk')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders] ([Id], [OrderDateTime], [CustomerName], [Status], [DoneBy]) VALUES (3, N'2022-07-09 00:00:00', N'Arçelik', N'Cancelled', N'Cavit')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders] ([Id], [OrderDateTime], [CustomerName], [Status], [DoneBy]) VALUES (4, N'2022-08-08 23:31:59', N'Fener', N'Continues', N'Test')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders] ([Id], [OrderDateTime], [CustomerName], [Status], [DoneBy]) VALUES (5, N'2022-08-08 23:37:54', N'Ümraniye', N'Continues', N'Ümraniye')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders] ([Id], [OrderDateTime], [CustomerName], [Status], [DoneBy]) VALUES (6, N'2021-08-04 23:43:28', N'Bruma', N'Completed', N'Gustova')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders] ([Id], [OrderDateTime], [CustomerName], [Status], [DoneBy]) VALUES (7, N'2021-09-09 13:16:36', N'Custom', N'Completed', N'Test')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders] ([Id], [OrderDateTime], [CustomerName], [Status], [DoneBy]) VALUES (8, N'2022-08-09 13:21:14', N'Tsubasa', N'Continues', N'Employee')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders] ([Id], [OrderDateTime], [CustomerName], [Status], [DoneBy]) VALUES (9, N'2021-10-27 13:37:36', N'New Customer', N'Completed', N'Test')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Orders] OFF

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[OrdersDetail] ON
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrdersDetail] ([Id], [ProductCode], [ProductName], [BuyQuantity], [SellQuantity], [CostRatio], [UnitCost], [TotalBuyPrice], [TotalSellPrice], [ShippingNumber], [Status], [TrackingNumber], [Description], [OrderId], [VendorId], [Currency]) VALUES (4, N'1', N'r', 12, 34, 2, 0, 56, 4, N'shipment', N'Completed', N'001', N'desc', 1, 2, N'TL')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrdersDetail] ([Id], [ProductCode], [ProductName], [BuyQuantity], [SellQuantity], [CostRatio], [UnitCost], [TotalBuyPrice], [TotalSellPrice], [ShippingNumber], [Status], [TrackingNumber], [Description], [OrderId], [VendorId], [Currency]) VALUES (5, N'12345-ABCN', N'Ipad', 5, 5, 10, 1000, 1000, 1500, N'S1', N'Getting ready', N'T11111', N'description1', 2, 1, N'TL')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrdersDetail] ([Id], [ProductCode], [ProductName], [BuyQuantity], [SellQuantity], [CostRatio], [UnitCost], [TotalBuyPrice], [TotalSellPrice], [ShippingNumber], [Status], [TrackingNumber], [Description], [OrderId], [VendorId], [Currency]) VALUES (6, N'0000-DDDD', N'Modem', 6, 6, 15, 200, 150, 225, N'S2', N'Getting ready', N'T11112', N'description2', 2, 2, N'TL')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrdersDetail] ([Id], [ProductCode], [ProductName], [BuyQuantity], [SellQuantity], [CostRatio], [UnitCost], [TotalBuyPrice], [TotalSellPrice], [ShippingNumber], [Status], [TrackingNumber], [Description], [OrderId], [VendorId], [Currency]) VALUES (7, N'98937-OPSKJ', N'ZTE', 7, 7, 10, 5000, 4500, 5500, N'S3', N'Getting ready', N'T11113', N'description3', 2, 1, N'TL')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrdersDetail] ([Id], [ProductCode], [ProductName], [BuyQuantity], [SellQuantity], [CostRatio], [UnitCost], [TotalBuyPrice], [TotalSellPrice], [ShippingNumber], [Status], [TrackingNumber], [Description], [OrderId], [VendorId], [Currency]) VALUES (8, N'11111-YUSH', N'Laptop', 8, 8, 6, 50, 50, 75, N'S4', N'Cancelled', N'T11114', N'description1', 3, 2, N'Dolar')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrdersDetail] ([Id], [ProductCode], [ProductName], [BuyQuantity], [SellQuantity], [CostRatio], [UnitCost], [TotalBuyPrice], [TotalSellPrice], [ShippingNumber], [Status], [TrackingNumber], [Description], [OrderId], [VendorId], [Currency]) VALUES (9, N'0090', N'Knife', 20, 677, 40, 0, 700, 343, N'9202930', N'Completed', N'ueı9q9u', N'test', 1, 2, N'Euro')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrdersDetail] ([Id], [ProductCode], [ProductName], [BuyQuantity], [SellQuantity], [CostRatio], [UnitCost], [TotalBuyPrice], [TotalSellPrice], [ShippingNumber], [Status], [TrackingNumber], [Description], [OrderId], [VendorId], [Currency]) VALUES (10, N'4', N'mouse', 12, 10, 10, 0, 10, 10, N's', N'Cancelled', N't', N'd', 3, 1, N'Euro')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrdersDetail] ([Id], [ProductCode], [ProductName], [BuyQuantity], [SellQuantity], [CostRatio], [UnitCost], [TotalBuyPrice], [TotalSellPrice], [ShippingNumber], [Status], [TrackingNumber], [Description], [OrderId], [VendorId], [Currency]) VALUES (11, N'rrrrrrrr', N'tank palet', 100, 8878, 40, 0, 288, 39, N'trk*0292', N'Getting ready', N'79ıwowu998', N'desc', 4, 1, N'Dolar')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[OrdersDetail] OFF
```

Comment: Show what the correct results would be - what type would hold the information?

Comment: int Month, int Count and double TotalSales will be enough, thank you.

Comment: You sample order details only link to order # 1 - I assume it was supposed to match the SQL sampe?

Comment: yes SQL sample is OK

Comment: What about which vendor? Or are you querying for only one vendor at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using EF Core, and have Navigation properties connecting your entities, you should just be able to use the Navigation properties to find the related entities and count or sum as necessary:

```
var ans = vendorList.Select(v => new {
    Vendor = v,
    Last3MonthsSales = v.OrderDetails
                            //.Where(od => od.Order.OrderDateTime >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3))
                            .GroupBy(od => new { od.Order.OrderDateTime.Year, od.Order.OrderDateTime.Month })
                            .Select(odg => new {
                                odg.Key.Month,
                                Count = odg.Count(),
                                TotalSales = odg.Sum(od => od.TotalSellPrice)
                            })
                            .ToList()
});
```

Comment: What if I want to group by `VendorId` and filter on `OrderId`, how can I select `order.OrderDateTime, order.CustomerId, orderdetail.TotalSellPrice, vendor.Name, orderdetail.Id, orderdetail.ProductCode, orderdetail.ProductName, orderdetail.Currency,    Sum (orderdetail.Quantity), Sum (orderdetail.BuyUnitPrice),  Sum (orderdetail.TotalBuyPrice)` ? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: @Cenk I don't see how you can group by `VendorId` and expect to have a single `OrderDateTime`?